# Can't remove italic text from collapsible content

Tags: html, css

I don't even any experiencing programming, but I am trying to put together a FAQ section for our help site and I wanted to use collapsible sections for the Q&A. I made it mostly work as I wanted, however, there is one thing I can't change at all. I have looked around and could not find what is wrong with the code. Any help would be highly appreciated. I really never did this before, so a total newbie here x

The HTML code I am using is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://content.ilabsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/gradifi.css" media="screen">

<div class="wrap-collabsible">
    <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox" value="on">
    <label class="lbl-toggle" for="collapsible">Question?</label>
    <div class="collapsible-content">
        <div class="content-inner">
            <p>Answer.</p>
        </div></div></div>
</html>




input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

.lbl-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    color: #ffff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00A9E0, #0085D5);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
    color: #7C5A0B;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .7rem;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f7f7f7, #f5f5f5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

[This is how the browsers displays it, the blue box text in Italic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyva2.png)

Update:

I am not sure if this is the way to post the resolution, but I finally figured it.

Under `.lbl-toggle {` instead of using `text-transform: none !important;` I used `font-style: normal; !important` . That did the trick! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also, when running on JSFiddle, it looks correct.
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=tQuhpoQwK3

Answer (score 0):

**Hello William,**

Please give this code a try and let me know the outcome, buddy. I certainly hope this help you solving this issue, mate!

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

.lbl-toggle {
    display: block;
    text-transform: none !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 0.6rem;
    color: #ffff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00A9E0, #0085D5);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
    color: #e3a514;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .7rem;
    font-style: normal !important;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f7f7f7, #f5f5f5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>No</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://content.ilabsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/gradifi.css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap-collabsible">
    <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox" value="on">
    <label class="lbl-toggle" for="collapsible">Question?</label>
    <div class="collapsible-content">
        <div class="content-inner">
            <p>Answer.</p>
        </div></div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey @Alvison Hunter. Thanks for taking the time to help. I tried this and it did not work. The browsers still show it in italic. I don't have access to change the <head> of the page, that is why I am using an external link for my stylesheet. What bugs me is I could change and edit everything in this page, but the italic. Even when I added `.body {` to the stylesheet, it changed the whole text editor page style, including the websites menu, my profile, etc. So I believe the software is not blocking my stylesheet, but again I am newbie. Would you have any other suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey Bill,  Even when in my snippet everything seems to be working fine, I did an extra adjustment in the CSS that I had by adding the font-style property to normal just in case something else is affecting this behavior and making the font to be italic in some browsers. Please try again and let me know how it goes this time, champ!